# Redirect to a hidden div

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to build a web app. I am having some problems with the following scenario.

1. The user clicks on submit button on 'home'
2. He is redirected to `home/ok` where I retrieve his info
3. from `home/ok` he is redirected back to `home#final`

But the thing is, final is hidden by default and it is not displaying. I have a JavaScript function that toggles final and it is displayed.

Is there anyway I can make the ok function redirect to the JavaScript function? I cannot add it on body `onload` since I don't want the success message to appear beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing something like:

```
<? $display = ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == base_url() . 'home/ok')? 'block': 'none'; ?>
<div id="final" style="<?=$display?>;">
 OK
</div>
```

To set the default display style based on which way the page is displayed.

You could also look in to `Flash data` in the `Session class`, see. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html which I think is used for what I think you want to achieve

Comment: Awesome. I looked into flashdata and this is just what i need. Thanks danneth.

Comment: Consider using `current_url()` instead of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Comment: I was pretty sure there was a CI way to get that info but I was too lazy to check, though `current_url` is not the same as `HTTP_REFERER`